# Type error with custom keydown event when trying to prevent default

Tags: events, elm

I realize I must be missing an argument somewhere or one of my arguments is incorrect, but after trying everything I can think of, I'm not sure what to do.

```
handleKeyDown : msg -> Attribute (Int -> Msg)
handleKeyDown message =
    custom "keydown" (Json.succeed { message = KeyPressed, stopPropagation = True, preventDefault = True })

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ input
            [ handleKeyDown ]
            [ text "" ]
        ]
```

Error

```
The 1st argument to `input` is not what I expect:

104|         [ input
105|>            [ handleKeyDown ]
106|             [ text "" ]

This argument is a list of type:

    List #(msg -> Attribute (Int -> Msg))#

But `input` needs the 1st argument to be:

    List #(Attribute msg)#
```

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems here:

1. `handleKeyDown` expects a `message` argument that you don't use and don't pass it. Therefore the type is `msg -> Attribute ...` rather than just `Attribute ...` as expected.
2. `KeyPressed` seems to have a payload of type `Int`. Therefore the return value is `Attribute (Int -> Msg)` rather than `Attribute Msg`.

Assuming you want to use the `message` argument and get the `keyCode` from the event, this should work:

```elm
handleKeyDown : (Int -> Msg) -> Html.Attribute Msg
handleKeyDown tag =
    let
        options message =
            { message = message
            , stopPropagation = True
            , preventDefault = True
            }

        decoder =
            Json.field "keyCode" Json.int
                |> Json.map tag
                |> Json.map options
    in
    Html.Events.custom "keydown" decoder

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ input
            [ handleKeyDown KeyPressed ]
            [ text "" ]
        ]
```

Here, `handleKeyDown` expects a tag/message with an `Int` payload. The internal event decoder retrieves the `keyCode`, wraps it in the tag you pass in, then wraps that in the options object with `preventDefault = True`.

But beware that `keyCode` is deprecated, and you probably want to use `code` or `key` instead, which both are strings.